# DLL loading sequence on Service startup

Tags: .net, windows, service

How can we trace the assembly loading sequence on windows service startup?

For example. When we start a service it loads all the reference assemblies and their dependencies; what i want to do is that which assemblies (OS, CLR or etc) are being loaded before actually starting the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use the `AssemblyLoad` event on `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` for this.**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += new AssemblyLoadEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad);

    Assembly.Load("ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib");

    Console.WriteLine("Completed loading");

    /*
     * This produced:

       Loaded assembly C:\Documents and Settings\...\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll
       Completed loading
     */
}

static void CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loaded assembly " + args.LoadedAssembly.Location);
}
```

Note that this will only work for assemblies that are loaded from the point you add the event. `mscorlib` for example is already loaded before the `Main` is called because you need this to be able to run `Main`.

Of course, if you create the domain yourself, you can add this event before the domain is started and you should see all the loaded assemblies.